# Does spark-sql support multiple delimiters in the input data?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input data with multiple single character delimiters as followed :

```
col1data1"col2data1;col3data1"col4data1
col1data2"col2data2;col3data2"col4data2
col1data3"col2data3;col3data3"col4data3
```

In the  above data the ["] ,[;]  are my delimiters.

Is there any way in **sparkSQL** to convert directly the input data( which is in  a file) into a **table with column names col1,col2,col3,col4**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **no**, spark-sql does not support multi-delimiter but one way to do it is trying to read it your file into an RDD and than parse it using regular splitting methods :

```
val rdd : RDD[String] = ???
val s = rdd.first()
// res1: String = "This is one example. This is another"
```

Let's say that you want to split on space and point break.

so we can consider apply our function on our `s` value as followed :

```
s.split(" |\\.")
// res2: Array[String] = Array(This, is, one, example, "", This, is, another)
```

now we can apply the function on the whole `rdd` :

```
rdd.map(_.split(" |\\."))
```

Example on your data :

```
scala> val s = "col1data1\"col2data1;col3data1\"col4data1"
scala> s.split(";|\"")
res4: Array[String] = Array(col1data1, col2data1, col3data1, col4data1)
```

More on string splitting :

- [A Scala split String example](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-split-string-example).
- [How to split String in Scala but keep the part matching the regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966831/how-to-split-string-in-scala-but-keep-the-part-matching-the-regular-expression)

Just remember that everything you can apply on a regular data type you can apply on a whole RDD, then all you have to do is converting your RDD to a DataFrame.

Comment: Hello, you closed my question and marked it as a duplicate to this.  It is not a duplicate.  This is about multipe-single character delimeters.  Mine is about a single-multi character delimeter.  Also, your response to this provides a single arrayed result, I need that single array transformed into a full row where each column value would be a indice of the array.

Comment: @testacc that doesn't change anything for you but this question is a duplicate variante of at least 10 questions on the site.